# Retrieve full path and file permissions of file modified between date range in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, acl, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-5.0

Considering this is my first post EVER on stackoverflow, and  quite new to PowerShell; I would request you all to be a bit gentle with your replies.

I am trying to get the contents modified between a date range for a HUGE production server. I want the contents to be exported to a .csv file with the columns representing the FullName, LastWriteTime, User/Group, Permissions of the associated folder housing the modified file, and if it has been inherited.

I have gone through TONS of forums, articles etc. but haven't been able to get the desired output. Here is the code I have been trying to run:

```
    $BaseFolder = "<path to be traversed>"

[datetime]$start = '2019-10-05 00:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2020-10-25 00:00:00'

$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $BaseFolder

#For each Group or Username in ACL   
$Files = ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access){

Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start -AND $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end } | 
Select-Object #FullName, LastWriteTime
              @{Name='Path';Expression={$_.FullName}},
              @{Name='LastWriteTime';Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}},
              @{Name='Group/User';Expression=$Access.IdentityReference},
              @{Name='Permissions';Expression=$Access.FileSystemRights},
              @{Name='Inherited';Expression=$Access.IsInherited}

} 

$Files | Export-Csv "<save-path>\Folder-Permissions-$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Here are some screenshots for a better idea:

Current output:
[image: Although this does generate some output, it is not what I desire.]

Desired output:
[image: I desire an output similar to this(I have heavily edited this screenshot)]

Any help is highly appreciated, and a big thank you in advance!

Regards,

Manny

Comment: So, you're getting the correct output, there are just _too many_ columns that you're not interested in in the CSV also, is that correctly understood?

Comment: Is this your actual code? There are some syntax issues when I try running it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I'm getting a partially correct result. I just want the FullName, LastWriteTime, Users, their associated ACLs, and if it ahs been inherited.

Comment: @marsze Correct, this is my actual code. I am getting an output similar to the 1st screenshot but desire one which is similar to the 2nd one. I have just edited out the path names. Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's the comment after `select-object` that messed up everything, because there's a linebreak after and the hashtables will not be passed as arguments to the command. Also there was an issue in your Expression definitions (you have to put them in a script block `{}`).

This should work:

```bsh
$BaseFolder = "<path to be traversed>"

[datetime]$start = '2019-10-05 00:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2020-10-25 00:00:00'

$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $BaseFolder

$Files = ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access){
    Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -Recurse -Force |
        Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start -AND $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end } | 
        Select-Object @{Name='Path';Expression={$_.FullName}},
                      @{Name='LastWriteTime';Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}},
                      @{Name='Group/User';Expression={$Access.IdentityReference}},
                      @{Name='Permissions';Expression={$Access.FileSystemRights}},
                      @{Name='Inherited';Expression={$Access.IsInherited}}
} 

$Files | Export-Csv "<save-path>\Folder-Permissions-$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It works as intended. I can't thank you enough. A very big thank you  @marsze.

Comment: Thank you for such a positive welcome! Hope I can help someone someday, just as you helped me.